# Unable to install matplotlib or any other packages

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, pip

This is what the cmd window reads after I run the pip install matplotlib command..

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:749)'),)': /simple/matplotlib/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:749)'),)': /simple/matplotlib/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:749)'),)': /simple/matplotlib/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:749)'),)': /simple/matplotlib/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:749)'),)': /simple/matplotlib/


Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/matplotlib/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/matplotlib/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:749)'),)) - skipping


ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib


Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:749)'),)) - skipping
```

How do I solve this ?
Any other ways to download it directly ?

Comment: Are you behind an office firewall? Looks like your machine is not able to authenticate the ssl certificate for pyi.org from where it is trying to download the files. Is it possible to login from a different nw? Perhaps personal wi-fi and try?

Comment: Actually I'm at a secure facility and I don't have any other way to access internet.. If there are any other ways I can download these packages directly from the net please do let me know

Comment: There are some instructions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-manually-install-python-packages/) and [here](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-manually-install-python-packages/). But, I have NOT done this and do not know if it the best way to do it. you would be doing it at your own risk. So, please be very very cautious